# csv command line argument for the user to access any csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to be able to read whatever csv file i have on my laptop and not just that specific one. how can i fix my code to ask the user to enter the input file name on the command line?

```
ifile = open('esxtopresult.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(ifile)
ofile = open('esxtopresult_mod2.csv', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(ofile)
```

Comment: use `argparse` module to take input from command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can get all your arguments like this:

```
import sys
print sys.argv[1]
ifile = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')

writer = csv.writer(ofile)


>>python code.py test/test.csv
```